# Gracefully handle AJAX requests in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I do a lot of UI coding involving sending AJAX REQUESTS to my backend PHP.

I've handled it with

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["UniquePostName"])){
/* Do Something*/
}
if(isset($_REQUEST["AnotherUniquePostName"])){
/* Do Something*/
}
```

However, this seems like a very poor way to handle this. Does anyone know of a more graceful way to handle many requests to PHP backend?

Comment: What is wrong with this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `switch ... case` statement.
It looks cleaner.

http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value){

    switch ($key){
        case "UniquePostName":
             //Do something
        break;
        case "AnotherUniquePostName":
             //Do something
        break;
        default:
             continue;
    }
}
```

You can as well change the way the form are passed and use the key to call a custom function. (you'll have to use whitelists for security concerns)

Comment: Yeah, I did consider this way, guess this is probably the best way to handle it.

Comment: Not sure why you have the foreach loop here. If the ajax request has more than one parameter, it will execute the switch 'n' number of times

Comment: yes, answer below is better for that reason, I upvoted it. This one only focus on the PHP side (and that maybe you'll have more than one key in the array).

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `action` variable with all your posts and you can use `switch` `case` in php.

Ajax requests

```
yourpage.php?action=UniquePostName&param1=val1&param2=val2
yourpage.php?action=AnotherUniquePostName&param1=val1&param2=val2
```

and in php

```
<?php
switch($_REQUEST['action']) {
case 'UniquePostName':
    //do stuff
    break;
case 'AnotherUniquePostName':
    //do stuff
    break;
default;
    //do stuff
    break;
}
?>
```